# my redux state does not change when using setTimeout()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, settimeout

I am currently developing a home page for my app and whenever the user makes a post that includes too large of a video file or image file, the user gets an error message stating that their file is too large. The only thing is, the text that is posted in the comment box is still sent to the database when I do not want anything sent to the database if a user gets an error about their post.

Here is my code:

```
const handleNewPost = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const arrayOfKeys = Object.keys(state.newPost)
  for (let i = 0; i <= arrayOfKeys.length; i++) {
    const formData = new FormData()
    if (arrayOfKeys[i] !== 'text' && ((arrayOfKeys[i] === 'image' && state.newPost[arrayOfKeys[i]].size < 10485760) || 
    (arrayOfKeys[i] === 'document' && state.newPost[arrayOfKeys[i]].size < 10485760))) {
      try {
        setLoading(true) 
        formData.append('file', state.newPost[arrayOfKeys[i]]);
        formData.append('upload_preset', process.env.REACT_APP_CLOUDINARY_PRESET)
        formData.append('api_key', process.env.REACT_APP_CLOUDINARY_APIKEY)
        const response = await axios.post(process.env.REACT_APP_CLOUDINARY_IMAGE_URL, formData).finally(el => {
          setLoading(false)
        })
        ref.current = await {...ref.current, [arrayOfKeys[i]]: response.data.secure_url}
      
    } catch (err) {
      setErrorMessage(err.message)
    }} else if (arrayOfKeys[i] === 'video' && state.newPost[arrayOfKeys[i]].size < 104857600) {
      try {
      setLoading(true)
      formData.append('file', state.newPost[arrayOfKeys[i]]);
      formData.append('upload_preset', process.env.REACT_APP_CLOUDINARY_PRESET)
      formData.append('api_key', process.env.REACT_APP_CLOUDINARY_APIKEY)
      const response = await axios.post(process.env.REACT_APP_CLOUDINARY_VIDEO_URL, formData).finally(el => {
        setLoading(false)
      })
      ref.current = {...ref.current, [arrayOfKeys[i]]: response.data.secure_url}
    } catch (err) {
      setErrorMessage(err.message)
    }
    } else if (arrayOfKeys[i] !== 'text' && state.newPost[arrayOfKeys[i]]){
      setErrorMessage('Video files must be 100MB or less, images and documents must be 10MB or less.')
      setContentError(arrayOfKeys[i])
      dispatch(createPosts('', 'text'))
      setTimeout(() => {
        setErrorMessage('')
        setContentError('')
      }, 5000)
    }
  }
  ref.current = {...ref.current, 'text': state.newPost.text} //I need to figure out a way to make the text empty if the last else if statement is executed above
  await postInformation.makeAPost(ref.current, savedUser)
  arrayOfKeys.forEach((key) => {
    dispatch(createPosts('', key))
  })
  setLoading(false)
  ref.current = ''
}
```

Here is the chunk of code that is specifically giving me the problem, I am trying to set the `text` state to an empty string but it remains as the string value given by the user. How could I use `setTimeout` while simultaneously changing my redux state to an empty string?

```
 else if (arrayOfKeys[i] !== 'text' && state.newPost[arrayOfKeys[i]]){
      setErrorMessage('Video files must be 100MB or less, images and documents must be 10MB or less.')
      setContentError(arrayOfKeys[i])
      dispatch(createPosts('', 'text'))
      setTimeout(() => {
        setErrorMessage('')
        setContentError('')
      }, 5000)
    }
  }
  ref.current = {...ref.current, 'text': state.newPost.text} //I need to figure out a way to make the text empty if the last else if statement is executed above
  await postInformation.makeAPost(ref.current, savedUser)
  arrayOfKeys.forEach((key) => {
    dispatch(createPosts('', key))
  })
  setLoading(false)
  ref.current = ''
}
```

**UPDATE 08/07/2022**

Here is the FULL code in question:

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import userInformation from "../../services/userInformation";
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";

import VectorIllustration from "./VectorIllustration";
import AvatarPicture from '../../images/AvatarPicture.png'
import HomeTwoToneIcon from '@mui/icons-material/HomeTwoTone';
import { Avatar } from "@nextui-org/react";
import PageviewTwoToneIcon from '@mui/icons-material/PageviewTwoTone';
import GroupsTwoToneIcon from '@mui/icons-material/GroupsTwoTone';
import EmailTwoToneIcon from '@mui/icons-material/EmailTwoTone';
import SettingsApplicationsTwoToneIcon from '@mui/icons-material/SettingsApplicationsTwoTone';
import { Button, IconButton, Input, InputAdornment } from "@mui/material";
import { TextField, Grid } from "@mui/material";
import ImageTwoToneIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ImageTwoTone';
import VideocamTwoToneIcon from '@mui/icons-material/VideocamTwoTone';
import AttachFileTwoToneIcon from '@mui/icons-material/AttachFileTwoTone';
import SendTwoToneIcon from '@mui/icons-material/SendTwoTone';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { storeUserInformation } from "../../reducers/storeInformationReducer";
import { createPosts } from "../../reducers/postReducer";
import { Loading } from '@nextui-org/react'
import ErrorTwoToneIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ErrorTwoTone';
import CheckBoxTwoToneIcon from '@mui/icons-material/CheckBoxTwoTone';
import DeleteForeverTwoToneIcon from '@mui/icons-material/DeleteForeverTwoTone';
import postInformation from "../../services/postInformation";
import '../../style-sheets/Home.css'
import FavoriteBorderTwoToneIcon from '@mui/icons-material/FavoriteBorderTwoTone';
import FavoriteIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Favorite';
import HeartBrokenIcon from '@mui/icons-material/HeartBroken';
import MessageIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Message';
import IosShareOutlinedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/IosShareOutlined';
import MessageOutlinedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/MessageOutlined';
import { storePostInformation } from "../../reducers/storePostReducer";
import InfiniteScroll from 'react-infinite-scroll-component'

const Home = () => {
  const state = useSelector(state => state)
  const ref = useRef();
  const [savedUser, setSavedUser] = useState()
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('')
  const [contentError, setContentError] = useState('')
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
  const [deleteItem, setDeleteItem] = useState(false)
  const [deleteVideo, setDeleteVideo] = useState(false)
  const [deleteDocument, setDeleteDocument] = useState(false)
  const [like, setLike] = useState(false)
  const [mouseOver, setMouseOver] = useState(false)
  const [reply, setReply] = useState(false)
  const [numberOfPosts, setNumberOfPosts] = useState(Array.from({ length: 5}))
  const [hasMore, setHasMore] = useState(true)
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const navigate = useNavigate();


      useEffect(() => {
        const initializer = async () => {
        const user = await JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('loggedAppUser'))
        setSavedUser(user)
        userInformation.setToken(user.token)
        const response = await userInformation.findUser(user.user.email)
        const arrayOfKeys = Object.keys(response.data.user)
        const arrayOfValues = Object.values(response.data.user)
        let i = 0
        arrayOfKeys.forEach(element => {
          dispatch(storeUserInformation(arrayOfValues[i], element))
          i++
        });
      }
        initializer()
      }, [])


      useEffect(() => {
        const grabPosts = async () => {
          const user = await JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('loggedAppUser'))
          const posts = await postInformation.getPosts(user.token)
          await posts.data.map((post, i) => {
          dispatch(storePostInformation(post, i))
          })
        }
      grabPosts()
      }, [])



const handleNewPost = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const arrayOfKeys = Object.keys(state.newPost)
  for (let i = 0; i <= arrayOfKeys.length; i++) {
    const formData = new FormData()
    if (arrayOfKeys[i] !== 'text' && ((arrayOfKeys[i] === 'image' && state.newPost[arrayOfKeys[i]].size < 10485760) || 
    (arrayOfKeys[i] === 'document' && state.newPost[arrayOfKeys[i]].size < 10485760))) {
      try {
        setLoading(true) 
        formData.append('file', state.newPost[arrayOfKeys[i]]);
        formData.append('upload_preset', process.env.REACT_APP_CLOUDINARY_PRESET)
        formData.append('api_key', process.env.REACT_APP_CLOUDINARY_APIKEY)
        const response = await axios.post(process.env.REACT_APP_CLOUDINARY_IMAGE_URL, formData).finally(el => {
          setLoading(false)
        })
        ref.current = await {...ref.current, [arrayOfKeys[i]]: response.data.secure_url}
      
    } catch (err) {
      setErrorMessage(err.message)
    }} else if (arrayOfKeys[i] === 'video' && state.newPost[arrayOfKeys[i]].size < 104857600) {
      try {
      setLoading(true)
      formData.append('file', state.newPost[arrayOfKeys[i]]);
      formData.append('upload_preset', process.env.REACT_APP_CLOUDINARY_PRESET)
      formData.append('api_key', process.env.REACT_APP_CLOUDINARY_APIKEY)
      const response = await axios.post(process.env.REACT_APP_CLOUDINARY_VIDEO_URL, formData).finally(el => {
        setLoading(false)
      })
      ref.current = {...ref.current, [arrayOfKeys[i]]: response.data.secure_url}
    } catch (err) {
      setErrorMessage(err.message)
    }
    } else if (arrayOfKeys[i] !== 'text' && state.newPost[arrayOfKeys[i]]){
      setErrorMessage('Video files must be 100MB or less, images and documents must be 10MB or less.')
      setContentError(arrayOfKeys[i])
      dispatch(createPosts('', 'text'))
      setTimeout(() => {
        setErrorMessage('')
        setContentError('')
      }, 5000)
    }
  }
  ref.current = await {...ref.current, 'text': state.newPost.text} //I need to figure out a way to make the text empty if the last else if statement is executed above
  await postInformation.makeAPost(ref.current, savedUser)
  arrayOfKeys.forEach((key) => {
    dispatch(createPosts('', key))
  })
  setLoading(false)
  ref.current = ''
}

const fetchMoreData = () => {
    if ((Object.entries(state.posts)).length - numberOfPosts.length < 5) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        setNumberOfPosts(numberOfPosts.concat(Array.from({length: ((Object.entries(state.posts)).length - numberOfPosts)})))
      }, 1500)
      setHasMore(false)
      return;
    } else {
      setTimeout(() => {
        setNumberOfPosts(numberOfPosts.concat(Array.from({length: 5})))
      }, 1500)
    }
}


  return (
    <>
    <div style={{
      position: 'relative',
      width: '1920px',
      height: '1080px',
      background: '#F7F9FE'}}>
      <VectorIllustration />
      <h1 style={{position: 'absolute', width: '30%', height: '5%', left: '20%', top: '4%', fontFamily: 'Outfit', fontStyle: 'normal', fontWeight: '400', fontSize: '32px', lineHeight: '40px', color: '#000000'}}>Welcome {state.storage.name}!</h1>
      <Link to='/home' style={{position: 'absolute', width: '10%', height: '6.5%', left: '2%', top: '20%', background: 'linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.47) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 93.56%)', textDecoration: 'none', color: '#FFFFFF', display: 'flex', textAlign: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', flexDirection: 'column'}}>Home</Link>
      <HomeTwoToneIcon style={{position: 'absolute', left: "3%", top: '21.5%', fontSize: '225%'}} color='primary' />
      <Avatar src={state.storage.profileImageURL ? state.storage.profileImageURL : AvatarPicture} style={{position: 'absolute', left: '83.5%', top: '11%', height: '132px', width: '132px'}}></Avatar>
      <Link to='/findasponsor' style={{position: 'absolute', width: '10%', height: '6.5%', left: '3.5%', top: '29%', textDecoration: 'none', color: '#FFFFFF', display: 'flex', textAlign: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', flexDirection: 'column'}}>Find A Sponsor</Link>
      <PageviewTwoToneIcon style={{position: 'absolute', left: "3%", top: '30.5%', fontSize: '225%', opacity: '0.7'}} />
      <Link to='/Groups' style={{position: 'absolute', width: '10%', height: '6.5%', left: '3.5%', top: '37%', textDecoration: 'none', color: '#FFFFFF', display: 'flex', textAlign: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', flexDirection: 'column'}}>Groups</Link>
      <GroupsTwoToneIcon style={{position: 'absolute', left: "3%", top: '38.6%', fontSize: '225%', opacity: '0.75'}}  />
      <Link to='/Messsages' style={{position: 'absolute', width: '10%', height: '6.5%', left: '3.5%', top: '45%', textDecoration: 'none', color: '#FFFFFF', display: 'flex', textAlign: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', flexDirection: 'column'}}>Messages</Link>
      <EmailTwoToneIcon style={{position: 'absolute', left: "3%", top: '46.5%', fontSize: '225%', opacity: '0.75'}} />
      <Link to='/Settings' style={{position: 'absolute', width: '10%', height: '6.5%', left: '3.5%', top: '54%', textDecoration: 'none', color: '#FFFFFF', display: 'flex', textAlign: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', flexDirection: 'column'}}>Settings</Link>
      <SettingsApplicationsTwoToneIcon style={{position: 'absolute', left: "3%", top: '55.5%', fontSize: '225%', opacity: '0.75'}} />
      <h1 style={{position: 'absolute', width: '201px', height: '76px', left: '4%', top: '68%', fontFamily: 'Outfit', fontStyle: 'normal', fontWeight: '500', fontSize: '26px', lineHeight: '38px', textAlign: 'center', color: '#1B1C1F', textDecoration: 'underline'}}>Go Local</h1>
      <p style={{position: 'absolute', width: '201px', height: '76px', left: '4%', top: '73%', fontFamily: 'Outfit', fontStyle: 'normal', fontWeight: '500', fontSize: '15px', textAlign: 'center', color: 'black'}}>Currently, you are viewing sponsors/ sponsees globally. Would you like to view only sponsors/sponsees in your country?</p>
      <Button style={{position: 'absolute', left: '4.5%', top: '85%', background: '#FFFFFF', borderRadius: '16px'}}>No</Button>
      <Button style={{position: 'absolute', left: '10.5%', top: '85%', background: '#FFFFFF', borderRadius: '16px'}} onClick={(e) => navigate('./Settings')}>Yes</Button>
      <h1 style={{position: 'absolute', top: '70%', left: '78%'}}>Trending Users</h1>
      <Link to='/home/:id' style={{position: 'absolute', top: '73.25%', left: '94%'}}>View all</Link>
      <p style={{position: 'absolute', top: '20%', left: '79%', fontFamily: 'Outfit', fontStyle: 'normal', fontWeight: '600', fontSize: '20px', lineHeight: '25px', textAlign: 'center'}}>{state.storage.followers}</p>
      <p style={{position: 'absolute', top: '23%', left: '77.5%', fontFamily: 'Outfit', fontStyle: 'normal', fontWeight: '300', fontSize: '16px', lineHeight: '20px', textAlign: 'center', color: '#A2ADBC'}}>Followers</p>
      <p style={{position: 'absolute', top: '20%', left: '94.5%', fontFamily: 'Outfit', fontStyle: 'normal', fontWeight: '600', fontSize: '20px', lineHeight: '25px', textAlign: 'center'}}>{state.storage.following}</p>
      <p style={{position: 'absolute', top: '23%', left: '93%', fontFamily: 'Outfit', fontStyle: 'normal', fontWeight: '300', fontSize: '16px', lineHeight: '20px', textAlign: 'center', color: '#A2ADBC'}}>Following</p>      
      <h1 style={{position: 'absolute', top: '28%', left: '83.6%', fontFamily: 'Outfit', fontStyle: 'normal', fontWeight: '500', fontSize: '20px', lineHeight: '25px', textAlign: 'center'}}>{state.storage.name}</h1>
      <p style={{position: 'absolute', width: '360px', height: '54px', left: '77.6%', top: '33%', fontFamily: 'Outfit', fontStyle: 'normal', fontWeight: '300', fontSize: '14px', lineHeight: '18px', textAlign: 'center', color: '#6D7683'}}>{state.storage.biography}</p>
      
      <form onSubmit={handleNewPost}>
      {contentError ? <TextField disabled size="large" rows={5} inputProps={{maxLength: 500}} multiline style={{position: 'absolute', left: '77%', top: '38%', width: '20%', color: 'red'}} value={errorMessage} /> : <TextField required size="large" rows={5} inputProps={{maxLength: 500}} multiline style={{position: 'absolute', left: '77%', top: '38%', width: '20%'}} placeholder='How are you feeling?' defaultValue='' disabled={loading} onChange={(e) => {
        dispatch(createPosts(e.target.value, 'text'))
      }} />}  

      {/* Add the ability to disable all buttons while loading is taking place, right now they still display while loading */}
      
      {state.newPost.image ? <Button onMouseOver={() => setDeleteItem(true)} onMouseLeave={() => setDeleteItem(false)} onClick={(e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        dispatch(createPosts('', 'image'))
      }} startIcon={deleteItem ? <DeleteForeverTwoToneIcon /> : <CheckBoxTwoToneIcon />} disabled={loading || errorMessage} variant='contained' color={deleteItem ? "error" : "success"} style={{position: 'absolute', left: '78%', top: '53%', borderRadius: '16px'}}>1 Image</Button> : <Button startIcon={contentError === 'image' ? <ImageTwoToneIcon style={{color: 'red'}}/> : <ImageTwoToneIcon />} variant="outlined" style={{position: 'absolute', left: '77%', top: '53%', background: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.32)', border: '1px solid rgba(45, 135, 255, 0.3)', borderRadius: '16px', color: contentError === 'image' ? 'red' : '', borderColor: contentError === 'image' ? 'red' : ''}} disabled={loading || errorMessage} component='label'>Add Image <input style={{pointerEvents: 'none'}} accept="image/*" type='file' hidden onChange={(e) => {
        setDeleteItem(false)
        dispatch(createPosts(e.target.files[0], 'image'))
      }}/></Button>}


      {state.newPost.video ? <Button onMouseLeave={() => setDeleteVideo(false)} onMouseOver={() => setDeleteVideo(true)} onClick={(e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        dispatch(createPosts('', 'video'))
      }} startIcon={deleteVideo ? <DeleteForeverTwoToneIcon /> : <CheckBoxTwoToneIcon />} disabled={loading || errorMessage} variant='contained' color={deleteVideo ? "error" : "success"} style={{position: 'absolute', left: '85%', top: '53%', borderRadius: '16px'}}>1 Video</Button> : <Button startIcon={contentError === 'video' ? <VideocamTwoToneIcon style={{color: 'red'}}/> : <VideocamTwoToneIcon />} variant="outlined" style={{position: 'absolute', left: '85%', top: '53%', background: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.32)', border: '1px solid rgba(45, 135, 255, 0.3)', borderRadius: '16px', color: contentError === 'video' ? 'red' : '', borderColor: contentError === 'video' ? 'red' : ''}} disabled={loading || errorMessage} component='label'>Add Video <input style={{pointerEvents: 'none'}} accept='video/*' type='file' hidden onChange={(e) => {
        setDeleteVideo(false)
        dispatch(createPosts(e.target.files[0], 'video'))
      }}/></Button>}

      {state.newPost.document ? <Button onMouseLeave={() => setDeleteDocument(false)} onMouseOver={() => setDeleteDocument(true)} onClick={(e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        dispatch(createPosts('', 'document'))
      }} startIcon={deleteDocument ? <DeleteForeverTwoToneIcon /> : <CheckBoxTwoToneIcon />} disabled={loading || errorMessage} variant='contained' color={deleteDocument ? "error" : "success"} style={{position: 'absolute', left: '92.5%', top: '53%', borderRadius: '16px'}}>1 File</Button> : <Button startIcon={contentError === 'document' ? <AttachFileTwoToneIcon style={{color: 'red'}}/> : <AttachFileTwoToneIcon />} variant="outlined" style={{position: 'absolute', left: '93%', top: '53%', background: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.32)', border: '1px solid rgba(45, 135, 255, 0.3)', borderRadius: '16px', color: contentError === 'document' ? 'red' : '', borderColor: contentError === 'document' ? 'red' : ''}} disabled={loading || errorMessage} component='label'>File <input accept=".pdf" type='file' hidden onChange={(e) => {
        setDeleteDocument(false)
        dispatch(createPosts(e.target.files[0], 'document'))
      }}/></Button>}


      {loading ? <Button disabled startIcon={<Loading style={{fontSize: '175%'}} color='white'/>} variant="outlined" style={{position: 'absolute', left: '77%', top: '58%', background: 'linear-gradient(180deg, #2D87FF 0%, #6099E5 100%)', borderRadius: '60px', color: 'white', width: '20.5%', height: '5%'}}>Loading</Button> : errorMessage ? <Button disabled startIcon={<ErrorTwoToneIcon color="white"/>} variant="outlined" style={{position: 'absolute', left: '77%', top: '58%', background: 'linear-gradient(180deg, #2D87FF 0%, #6099E5 100%)', borderRadius: '60px', color: 'white', width: '20.5%', height: '5%'}}>Error</Button> : <Button type="submit" startIcon={<SendTwoToneIcon style={{fontSize: '175%'}} />} variant="outlined" style={{position: 'absolute', left: '77%', top: '58%', background: 'linear-gradient(180deg, #2D87FF 0%, #6099E5 100%)', borderRadius: '60px', color: 'white', width: '20.5%', height: '5%'}}>Post</Button>}
      </form>

      {(Object.values(state.posts)).length !== 0 ? 
      <InfiniteScroll height='100%' dataLength={numberOfPosts.length} next={fetchMoreData} hasMore={hasMore} loader={<Loading style={{position: 'absolute', left: '50%'}}/>}
       id='all-post-container' scrollThreshold={0.5} endMessage={<p style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
       <b>That's all folks!</b>
     </p>}
       style={{position: 'absolute', top: '25%', left: '20%', backgroundColor: '#F7F9FE', height: '72%', width: "54%", borderRadius: '30px'}}>
      <Grid
        container
        direction="column"
        justifyContent="center"
        alignItems="center"
        spacing={45}
      >
      {numberOfPosts.map((key, i) => {
      return (
        <Grid container item>
        <div id="post-container" style={{margin: '5%', position: 'absolute', width: '90%', height: '40%', backgroundColor: 'white', borderRadius: '30px', overflow: 'auto'}}>
          <Avatar src={<AvatarPicture/>} style={{position: 'absolute', left: '1%', top: '3%', height: '60px', width: '60px'}} size='lg'></Avatar>
          <p style={{position: 'absolute', left: '9%', top: '-5%', fontFamily: 'Outfit', fontStyle: 'normal', fontWeight: '500', fontSize: '20px', lineHeight: '25px', overflow: 'auto'}}>@{state.posts[i].username}</p>
          <p style={{position: 'absolute', left: '9%', top: '10%', fontFamily: 'Outfit', fontStyle: 'normal', fontWeight: '400', fontSize: '16px', lineHeight: '20px', color: '#6D7683'}}>{state.storage.location}</p>
          <p style={{position: 'absolute', left: '20%', top: '10%', fontFamily: 'Outfit', fontStyle: 'normal', fontWeight: '400', fontSize: '16px', lineHeight: '20px', color: '#2D87FF'}}>{state.posts[i].date}</p>
          <div id="text-container" style={{position: 'absolute', top: '30%', left: '5%', backgroundColor: '#FFFBEE', height: '30%', width: '90%', borderRadius: '16px', overflow: 'scroll'}}><p style={{position: 'absolute', top: '20%', left: '50%'}}>{state.posts[i].text}</p></div>
          <TextField InputProps={{
            startAdornment: (
              <InputAdornment>
                <Avatar src={state.storage.profileImageURL} />
              </InputAdornment>
            ),
            classes: {
              notchedOutline: 'notched-outline-border-radius'
          }
          }} maxRows={10} inputProps={{maxLength: 500}} multiline style={{position: 'absolute', left: '5%', top: '78%', width: '90%', background: '#F8FAFF', border: '1px solid #D9E1F9', borderRadius: '16px'}} placeholder='Write your comment'></TextField>
          <IconButton onClick={() => setLike(!like)} style={{ position: 'absolute', top: '60%', left: '5%'}} onMouseLeave={() => setMouseOver(false)} onMouseOver={() => setMouseOver(true)}>{like && mouseOver ? <HeartBrokenIcon style={{color: 'red'}}/> : like ? <FavoriteIcon style={{color: 'red'}} /> : <FavoriteBorderTwoToneIcon /> }</IconButton>
          <p style={{position: 'absolute', top: '59%', left: '9%'}}>{state.posts[i].likes}</p>
          <IconButton onClick={() => setReply(!reply)} style={{ position: 'absolute', top: '60%', left: '13%'}}>{reply ? <MessageIcon color="primary"/> : <MessageOutlinedIcon/>}</IconButton>
          <p style={{position: 'absolute', top: '59%', left: '17%'}}>{state.posts[i].comments}</p>
          <IconButton style={{ position: 'absolute', top: '60%', left: '23%'}}><IosShareOutlinedIcon /></IconButton>
          <p style={{position: 'absolute', top: '59%', left: '27%'}}>{state.posts[i].shares}</p>
        </div>
        </Grid>
      )})}
      </Grid>
      </InfiniteScroll> : <div id='content-loader' style={{position: 'absolute', top: '25%', left: '20%', backgroundColor: '#F7F9FE', height: '72%', width: "54%", borderRadius: '30px'}}><Loading size='lg' style={{position: 'absolute', left: '50%', top: '50%'}}/></div>}
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible code sample.

Comment: @c0m1t i made an update.

Comment: It is kinda hard to follow the code or even understand the issue you are facing. You probably can remove redundant code and create a codesandbox with less than 50 lines of code. What are you trying to achieve by this line `ref.current = await {...ref.current, 'text': state.newPost.text}`?

Comment: im adding a 'text' key to the current object

Comment: Yes I can see . But I do not understand using `await` before an object. You are storing your current values in a ref? Why don't you read them from state? You probably can use React state instead of redux state for form values. Why dont you set the `text` on the `ref` to an empty string right before `setTimeout`?

Answer (score 0):

1. `await` is only used for functions not values.
2. You do not need a ref. You can declare a `data` variable inside `handleNewPost` function instead.
3. You have lots of duplicate code which you can refactor.
4. You can validate files right after user selects a file from the file system. If the file size is bigger than the limit, set the error.
5. You can do validation in `handleNewPost` as well.
6. You have 3 conditions in `handleNewPost`. First two conditions are valid. Let's say you define a variable named `isValid` when either the first two conditions are`ture`. You call `postInformation.makeAPost(data, savedUser)` if `isValid` is `true`. Otherwise you transform the first argument of `makeAPost` however it suits you. `postInformation.makeAPost({...data, text: ''}, savedUser)`.

Here is a [minimal example](https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-allen-j9phn0?file=/src/App.js) of code. I have not used Redux in it, because I don't believe this is an issue regarding Redux.